# Is there a modern solution to update Angular .xlf files?

Tags: angular, localization, xliff

We are currently localizing our Angular app and are faced with the problem that whenever there is a change to one of our source files, the translation files need to be updated by hand, which is a tedious process, even with only one language. I was able to find an [old tool](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport) which reportedly still works, but uses deprecated methods and has mostly outdated dependencies.

Does anyone know of an up-to-date tool which does the same thing? Or maybe just a workflow which makes the process of updating the files less tedious?

**Edit:**

Our file structure is that of a normal Angular project. We have a folder *locale* within the folder *src*, where translation files are kept. We have a *messages.xlf* containing all the English terms and a *messages.de.xlf* translating them back to German (we are a German company but want the application to be in English by default). The translation is done in-house.

But since the application is constantly being extended with new features, every time there are any changes to the code, a new *messages.xlf* file must be created. We then have to go into the *messages.de.xlf* file and manually change all entries which have changed their position in the source code and we also need to manually add/replace/delete all terms which were changed. What we're looking for is a way to automate this process.

Comment: Are you talking about generating the files or replacing them?

Comment: @Moshezauros Replacing/Updating

Comment: @TigersEye120 Could you describe your process and file/project structure in more detail? Who is doing the actual translating? Are you working with external translators?

Comment: @martin_wun I've updated my question. Hopefully it's a bit clearer now what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit II**: https://github.com/daniel-sc/ng-extract-i18n-merge probably solves all your problems :-) (This is based on the libraries from the old answer below and packages everything nice and clean as an angular plugin/builder.)

*Previous answer:*

Assuming you assign [explicit IDs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-optional-manage-marked-text) to your translation units (you should!), you can use [xml_normalize](https://github.com/daniel-sc/xml_normalize) to solve some of the problems involved:

- remove "notes" tags (they normally only clutter diff/PRs)
- sort units by "id"

This can be archived by running `npm i --save-dev xml_normalize` and adding the following line to the "scripts" section of your `package.json` (here using XLIFF 2):

```json
"extract-i18n": "ng extract-i18n --format xlf2 && node node_modules/xml_normalize -n -i [PATH_TO]/messages.xlf -o [PATH_TO]/messages.xlf -r /xliff/file/unit/notes -s /xliff/file/unit/@id",
```

With these two things, running `npm run extract-i18n`, you should get small and easy to read diffs.

You'd still need to add/remove added/removed translation units to your language specific messages.de.xlf though.

(Disclosure: I am the author of xml_normalize.)

**edit:** If you use XLIFF 2.0 you can additionally use [xliff-simple-merge](https://github.com/daniel-sc/xliff-simple-merge) to archive an automatic merging of added/removed translations. Details in this [blog post](https://dev.to/danielsc/angular-i18n-update-workflow-25p6).

Answer (score 0):

@TigeryEye120 Thank you for the edit. It is much clearer now. I would suggest you look into some of the translation tools that support XLIFF as a source. You would then open the English source XLIFF in this tool, do the translations within the tool and save/export the translated German file.

If you want to automate this process, I suggest you look into the open-source [Okapi framework](http://okapiframework.org/), which has very good support for XLIFF and also supports various machine translation providers.